# I want string to be a widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I mean that I want to get scores code from api:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well their is a widget called Text()

provide the String as it text then it will accept it

```
body: Text("any text")
```

Comment: I mean that I want ot get string Like the score  code ( Text("nice to meet you " )) to to display  in the body

Comment: get data from api is a widget

Comment: you are showing the test file not the main.
any way you have to make request the data from the API and added FutureBuilder Widgit to show the arrived text

Comment: I don''t want show the Text("any text");

I want to show the string content the Widget

Comment: string text = "Container(),"

Comment: I mean that I do not want to display  the text display  work Container 
I want to display  text like a Widget

Comment: @VanNak , Did you get the solution to this? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) widget with string `text`

```dart
body: Text(text),
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for learning purposes and you want to know how to use a widget as a parameter you can do the following:

```
Text text = Text("Something"); // This way you specify exactly the type `Text`
```

or

```
Widget text = Text("Somethig"); // This way you can associate any widget to text
```

or

```
var text = Text("Something"); // var can be used with any type
```

Then you can use whenever you want in your code as long as it require a Widget as a child whitout any need for casting.

For you to create a widget that you can associate values to it you can go for something like this:

```
Widget myText({String value}) => Text(value);
```

There are many approaches depending on your need, and I strongly advice you to follow some tutorials for beginners first like [Angela Yu bootcamp](https://www.udemy.com/course/flutter-bootcamp-with-dart/) or any others and also use Flutter documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
body: Text(text),
```

Answer (score 0):

[String](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.0/dart-core/String-class.html) is not and will not be a widget. What you are probably looking for is the widget to display a string in your UI: [Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html).

In your exemple, you can correct it like this :

```
return Scaffold(
   body: Text("Hello World")
);
```

[See exemple on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1)